# Fortran95 access large files fast using direct access

Tags: performance, file, io, fortran

I am currently working on a problem which requires me to store a large amount of well structured information in a file.
It is more data than I can keep in memory, but I need to access different parts of it very often and would like to do so as quickly as possible (of course).
Unfortunately, the file would be large enough that actually reading through it would take quite some time as well.

From what I have gathered so far, it seems to me that ACCESS="DIRECT" would be a good way of handling this problem. Do I understand correctly that with direct access, I am basically pointing at a specific chunk of memory and ask "What's in there?"? And do I correctly infer from that, that reading time does not depend on the overall file size?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You may have got to the point where familiarising yourself with a file format such as HDF5 becomes worth the effort.  There is an extensive set of library routines for manipulating HDF5 files, to save you the effort of rolling your own.  Oh, and there are other file formats / libraries worth considering, do some searching around.

Comment: Another advantage of HDF5 or netcdf or similar is that they permit writing by multiple processes, which "native" Fortran methods do not support. Thus if you intend to parallelise the code at any point in the future (surely something likely for one with a large memory foot print) investing in a pure Fortran implementation may be a waste of effort in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of an `ACCESS='DIRECT'` file as a file consisting of a number of fixed size records. You can do operations like read or write record #N in `O(1)` time. That is, in order to access record #N you don't need to scan through all the preceding #M (M<N) records in the file.

If this maps reasonably well to the problem you're trying to solve, then `ACCESS='DIRECT'` might be the correct solution in your case. If not, `ACCESS='STREAM'` offers a little bit more flexibility in that the size of each record does not need to be fixed, though you need to be able to compute the correct file offset yourself. If you need even more flexibility there's things like NetCDF, or HDF5 like @HighPerformanceMark suggested, or even things like sqlite.